# Remove one of two elements if elements have same text

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete widget in vanilla js.I have an `input` and a `ul` element in my html.Also set `data-list` attribute for autocomplete.

Basicly, in my js, i get data-list and filter it when i type the input field.

Since i create `li` element in my js when typing, i have same text over again when i type.

So, can i remove same li element?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lvck9cn/)**

**html:**

```
<input class="input" type="text" data-list="black,white,red"/>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

**js:**

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var list = document.querySelector(".list");

// Made data list array
var data_list = input.getAttribute("data-list");
data_list = data_list.split(",");

var typing_arr = [];
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var typing = data_list;

  // Filter data-list array 
  typing = typing.filter(function(item) {
    return item.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1;
  });

  typing_arr = typing;

  // Show data-list according to filter
  typing_arr.map(function(list_item) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    list.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = list_item;

    //Remove same elements from list
    if (list.children.length > typing.length) {
      console.log("Remove the same!")
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: I don't get your way of thinking, why do you need such code? If you click, e.g. `backspace` button, you are adding 3 new `li` elements to the list. But, why?

Comment: For autocomplete  purpose @Kinduser

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want to filter the list from all duplicated elements? So it will be always only 3 `li` items with different values?

Comment: İf you type 'b' you see "black" is shown. But when i clear input field there are 4 items (2 black items). I want to get rid of this. @Kinduser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you search you have to clear the old list. So, just add

```
list.innerHTML = '';
```

to the beggining of the function and you're done. 
Here:

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var list = document.querySelector(".list");

// Made data list array
var data_list = input.getAttribute("data-list");
data_list = data_list.split(",");

var typing_arr = [];
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  list.innerHTML = '';  //CHANGE
  var typing = data_list;

  // Filter data-list array 
  typing = typing.filter(function(item) {
    return item.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1;
  });

  typing_arr = typing;

  // Show data-list according to filter
  typing_arr.map(function(list_item) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    list.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = list_item;

    //Remove same elements from list
    if (list.children.length > typing.length) {
      console.log("Remove the same!")
    }

  });

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lvck9cn/3/